# while creating a trigger I got an error ie incorrect syntax near end

Tags: sql-server

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[student_on_insert]
ON [dbo].[Student]
FOR INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM student

    DECLARE @id INT

    SELECT @id = rollno FROM inserted

    INSERT INTO [dbo].student_adm
    VALUES (@id, 'student having rollno' + CAST(@id AS VARCHAR(4)) + ' was admitted .' + CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR(50))
END
```

Comment: Just on the error : you missed out a `)`. You have bigger issues with your trigger. It should not have a result set return. You are assuming the trigger only fired for one row only

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` that causes this trigger to fire inserts 10 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 10 rows. Which of those rows will your code select from `Inserted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger might get **multiple rows** in the `Inserted` pseudo table - you can therefore **NOT** just do a selection like this:

```
SELECT @id = rollno FROM inserted
```

This would select *one arbitrary row* out of all the rows being inserted - and ignore all the others.

Instead, you need to use a **set-based** approach and deal with the fact that multiple rows might have been inserted. You need to change your code to something like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[student_on_insert]
ON [dbo].[Student]
FOR INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].student_adm
        SELECT 
            i.rollno,  
            'Student with rollno: ' + CAST(@id AS VARCHAR(4)) + 
                 ' was admitted. ' + CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR(50))
        FROM 
            Inserted i
END
```

Answer (score 0):

One missing parenthesisat end of values(..) statement. Try below

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[student_on_insert]
on [dbo].[Student]
for insert 
as
begin
        select * from student
        declare @id int
        select @id=rollno from inserted
        insert into [dbo].student_adm
        values(@id,'student having rollno'+cast(@id as varchar(4))+' was admitted .'+cast(getdate() as varchar(50)))
end
```